# How do I hide, delete or manage grease pencil lines in 2.8?

Tags: grease-pencil

I drew on a face reference photo with the grease pencil by holding D. I want to hide the lines I drew. Some sources say to press N and then go to the "grease pencil" section, but that appears to be missing/moved in 2.8. Trying to search for 2.8 grease pencil gives me a bunch of long tutorials on creating 2D animations with the new grease pencil, but not a simple answer on how to hide the lines I drew. How do I hide or manage them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grease Pencil became a separate object (and more complex) type in 2.8. If you just draw with D, you now create an *Annotation* and you can toggle it's visibility:

- globally in the Overlays section

[image]

- individually by toggling an annotation layer in the N panel -> Annotations
  [image]

Comment: Is there a way to move part of a grease pencil drawing to it's own layer?

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think it is possible to edit Annotations afterwards, maybe in some future 2.8 version.

Comment: Is there a way to make annotation stick to the surface of the object? Like in grease pencil "Stroke placement", but I don't see it anywhere near annotations.